# How do I disable a password check on my computer using a local account?

Tags: passwords, windows-8.1, login

Is there a way that I can disable my password on login **but only while still using my MS account?** It seems like there should be a way, and I disabled login after screensaver and waking up computer, yet I've never figured out how to log in automatically.

**I would prefer a solution without 3rd party software.** If it *does* have to be done with software, open source would be highly appreciated.

Comment: you mean you want the computer to automatically login without without deleting the password from the account settings?

Comment: @Sickest Basically. I want it to automatically login without creating a *local* account on my computer.

Comment: @Sickest I still want a *Microsoft account* stored locally on my computer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`How do I disable a password check on my computer using a local account.`

> 1. Boot your PC and enter your password.
> 2. Press Win-X (by which I mean hold down the Windows key and then tap X).
> 3. In the pop-up menu that appears, click Command Prompt (Admin).
> 4. In the command prompt, type control userpasswords2, then press Enter. (If this sounds familiar, it's because the same command works
>      in earlier versions of Windows.)
> 5. In the User Accounts dialog that appears, uncheck the box marked Users must enter a user name and password to use this computer.
> 6. Click OK, then confirm the automatic sign-in option by entering your password (twice).
> 7. Reboot.